# When does a fixed window start in apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I have a join job with a fixed windowing strategy. So the join job reads from two streams:

```
1. Record 1: ts: 2022-Mar-23-13:00:00, key: abcdef
2. Record 2: ts: 2022-Mar-23-18:00:00, key: xyzefg
```

If I use a fixed window of 24 hours and I keep reading from this stream of data, when does the pane start for Record1 and Record2?

Is this correct?

```
Pane1: start = 2022-Mar-23-13:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-13:00:00, key =abcdef
Pane2: start = 2022-Mar-23-18:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-18:00:00, key= xyzefg
```

Or is this correct?

```
Pane1: start = 2022-Mar-23-13:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-13:00:00, key =abcdef
Pane2: start = 2022-Mar-23-13:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-13:00:00, key= xyzefg
```

Or is this correct?

```
Pane1: start = 2022-Mar-23-00:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-00:00:00, key =abcdef
Pane2: start = 2022-Mar-23-00:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-00:00:00, key= xyzefg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the last. For fixed windows, they are always 24 hours long*, and when they get assigned to an element they typically extend both before and after the element's timestamp (unless it happens to be right on the boundary).

`* Well, technically the end of the window is one microsecond before the next window starts, so as to prevent overlap and ambiguity of which window any timestamp belongs to.`

Comment: Thanks! But with a session window of same duration(24 hours), I can achieve this?             
`Pane1: start = 2022-Mar-23-13:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-13:00:00, key =abcdef
Pane2: start = 2022-Mar-23-18:00:00, end = 2022-Mar-24-18:00:00, key= xyzefg`

Comment: Sessions don't have constant duration--they have a "gap" parameter that determines the minimum gap between consecutive events /within the same key/ that defines the breaks between windows. You could take a look at https://colab.research.google.com/github/apache/beam/blob/master/examples/notebooks/tour-of-beam/windowing.ipynb